# How to install the Selenium IDE(selenium-ide-2.9.0.xpi) in Firefox 45.0?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

Unable to install the Selenium IDE (selenium-ide-2.9.0.xpi), after hitting the allow button, it begins the downloading part and even after completing the downloading the Install button is disabled.

[[image: Install button is Disabled]]

Comment: download IDE from here :- http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing legacy version of Firefox. You have to uninstall the current one then download the old version from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/41.0/win32/en-US/.

Comment: Installation completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Record and play tests are very hard to maintain. Please consider developing a [test automation framework](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/automated-testing-framework-selenium).

For brittle tests go here: [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared