# Scheduling through Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 3.17.0 in chrome for recording scripts.

Is there any way to schedule the scripts through Selenium IDE like run the scripts/tests every 1 hr.

i can obviously export the scripts/tests to some programming languages and run a scheduler quartz to schedule it but was looking if there is anything native built in Selenium IDE.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Selenium IDE jobs used to be able to run from the command line (using html runner). I would set this up to run as a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, scheduling is no longer supported in the latest version. If you do want though, you can install an older version and enable scheduling. For that, you would need to download a legacy version, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011951/6505847).

[Here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/download-selenium-ide/) is another good walkthrough

**Steps:**

Selenium IDE > Options > Schedule tests to run periodically

[image]

[image]

**My suggestion would be to not run it using IDE.
I'd suggest doing this:**

1. Create a WebDriver (or RC if you wish) test using your preferred language.
2. If using linux, just use `crontab` to set up a 15 minute cronjob. If using windows, use task scheduler to run your test.

Comment: I couldn't find solid evidence on why they deprecated this feature, but from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/258#issuecomment-399855144) it seems like they just transitioned it onto CLI runners and so it was redundant to have it in the IDE.